# bash + how to print list of devices In continuous order

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, awk

the file - `list_of_disk_devices.txt` , contain list of disk devices

the problem with file - list_of_disk_devices.txt , is that list of devices isn't sorted with the right order

actually we need to print the order as the following:

```
sdb
.
.
sdz
sdaa
.
.
.
sdaz
sdba
.
.
.
sdbz
```

and file looks like:

```
more list_of_disk_devices.txt

sdau
sdav
sdaw
sdax
sday
sdaz
.
.
.
sdp
sdq
sdr
sds
sdz
sdaa
sdab
sdac
sdad
sdae
sdaf
sdag
.
.
.
sdba
sdam
sdbb
sdan
sdbc
sdao
sdat
sdau
sdav
sdd
sde
sdf
sdg
sdk
sdl
.
.
.
sds
sdt
sdu
sdv
sdw
sdx
sdy
sdz
sdaa
sdab
sdac
sdad
sdae
sdaf
.
.
.
sdak
sdal
sdba
sdbe
sdap
sdbh
sdas
sdat
```

we also tried with sort command with many options but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gawk` you can specify the sort order of the array via a user defined function.

```
gawk '
    function my_comp(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
        if (length(v1) > length(v2)) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (length(v1) == length(v2)) {
            return (v1 >= v2);
        }
        return -1;
    }

    {
        a[NR] = $1;
    }

    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "my_comp";
        for (k in a) {
            print a[k];
        }
    }
' list_of_disk_devices.txt
```